# Exchange Disconnecting on EHLO with remote telnet

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, windows, smtp

When I go to the local terminal on my Exchange box (SBS 2008) I can do this:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 25
220 Exchange banner here
EHLO example.com
250 Server name
```

However when I go from another box, or from the actual IP of the server I get this:

```
telnet 192.168.21.20 25
220 Exchange banner here
EHLO example.com
421 4.4.1 Connection timed out
```

Connection to host lost.

The odd thing is, this server is currently in production and working fine (receiving mail for our entire domain). But my C# programs can't send mail to it (they get this same error).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The Exchange server appears to be trying to connect back to you (something like ident?), so you should try a packet sniffer (like Wireshark) to see *where* it is trying to connect.

---

Another way to interpret that message. SMTP, like most internet protocols, uses `CR/LF` pair as line terminator. And so does the telnet protocol. However, it might happen that in your second example, the client (is it "telnet" or something else?) does *not* send the correct line ending - maybe it sends just `LF` or something entirely different. Again, use Wireshark to find out.

---

Related to #2 above: Maybe your second machine has an antivirus program that tries to be smart and intercepts SMTP connections? I've seen many occassions of them breaking POP3.

Answer (score 0):

In your application are you using a standard smtp lib or are you sending the commands down a raw socket? If you are sending the commands down raw check whether or not you are sending a \r\n after the command.

J

Comment: Well telnet isn't working either, so it's a bigger issue than my program. But no I'm using the standard .NET System.Net libraries.

Comment: Are you telneting to localhost on the server or to the publicly facing IP?

J

Comment: localhost works (as shown above), public ip does not. I'd think it would be a windows firewall issue, but I get the server connection banner.